# Node sync is freezing at 860000 blocks on mainnet

Tags: nodeos, mainnet, node, full-node

I need help syncing the node to mainnet. 
It is freezing at 860000 blocks (860112 to be precise as seen in mongodb).
On 2 different servers - same result. 
Software 1.1 built with sql plugin (the only difference to default build config, but the plugin is disabled)
Os: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

solved by adding `chain-state-db-size-mb = 65536` to config.ini.

thanx to Cryptolions in Telegram :)